Recreating waves/sound given a frequency spectrum?
I'm currently working on a project with a decibel meter capable of measuring the frequency spectrum of a given sound. It gives it in the form of 64 bands from 0 Hz - 8 kHz (250 Hz increments) and I'm wishing to recreate the waveform and ultimately play the generated wave form as audio. Unsure of whether any of this is even possible or not, I decided to at least try to recreate the wave form using basic matplotlib and numpy ifft code but this is what I get:

I know my code is somewhat correct because when I try with a basic spectrum it looks as expected:

I'm new to DSP so I'm not sure where to go from here. Am I missing some sort of data processing before I can do iffts? Is this just impossible given the information I have? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Do you have the phase of the spectrum or only the magnitude ? Without the phase you are missing half of the information (and a very important half at that).

The problem you have, is that what you're working with is not the frequency spectrum. It's the magnitude spectrum, which is only a part of the frequency spectrum. You can't recreate anything worth listening to if you don't have the phase information. Do you have access to that as well?

@Hilmar beat me to it
